# Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, react-native

[enter image description here][1]I was using facing issue while open camera using action sheet and getting following error.

> CameraProxy.js:105 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
>       at successCallback (CameraProxy.js:105)

My ionic camera version is `"@ionic-native/camera": "^4.3.0"`.

Is there an issue with actionsheet or native plugin?

My camera is getting started but not working.

The below was typescript code for camera

```
 const actionSheet = this.actionSheetController.create({
      title: 'Actions',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'upload',
        role: 'destructive',
        icon: 'upload',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('camera clicked');
          const options: CameraOptions = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
          };

      this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        this.ProfileInfo.profileImagePath = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData;
        this.ProfileInfo.profileimage = imageData;
        this.updateImage(this.ProfileInfo);

      }, (err) => {

      });
    }
  }, {
    text: 'camera',
    icon: 'camera',
    handler: () => {
      console.log('camera clicked');
      const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
      };

      this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

        this.ProfileInfo.profileImagePath = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData;
        this.ProfileInfo.profileimage = imageData;
        this.updateImage(this.ProfileInfo);

      }, (err) => {

      });
    }
  }, {
    text: 'Cancel',
    icon: 'close',
    role: 'cancel',
    handler: () => {
      console.log('Cancel clicked');
    }
  }]
});
actionSheet.present();
```

Comment: Can you provide us the typescript code where you are invoking the camera plugin?

Comment: I was use actionsheet for invoking camera plugin in above code

Comment: There is no problem with your code. I used your code in my project and it's working fine. I used the same version of the camera plugin. By any chance are you using Angular 6?

Comment: I am using angular 5

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?